# Express routing Cassandra batch query

Tags: node.js, express, cassandra

I have a NodeJs / Express server where I need to route a Cassandra batch query with Update, Delete and Insert.

I tried to use method all but it is not working. How can I make this api works?

I am using Cassandra-driver
http://datastax.github.io/nodejs-driver/features/batch/

Here is my routing:

```
router.all('/:help_id',function(req,res){
  const help_id = req.params.help_id;
  const question = req.body.question;
  const answer = req.body.answer;
  const topic = req.body.topic;
  const help_order = req.body.help_order;
  if(!!help_id && !!question){
    const query1 = "UPDATE helps SET question=?, answer=?, topic=?, help_order=? WHERE help_id=?";
    const query2 = "DELETE FROM topics WHERE topic=? AND help_order=? AND help_id=?";
    const query3 = "INSERT INTO topics(topic,help_order,help_id,question,answer) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    const queries = [
      { query: query1, params: [question,answer,topic,help_order,help_id] },
      { query: query2, params: [topic,help_order,help_id] },
      { query: query3, params: [topic,help_order,help_id,question,answer] }
    ];
    client.batch(queries,{ prepare: true },function(err){
      if(!!err){
        res.status(404).send({message: 'No help to update found.'});
      } else {
        const data = [];
        data["error"] = 0;
        data["Help"] = "Help was updated.";
        res.json(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: As a side note, using batches as an optimization is an anti pattern for cassandra and is more than 2x as expensive than just doing the writes. Unless you need it for the atomic (no isolation) properties, its recommended not to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

router.post seems to work for update, delete and insert.